# How can I assign this variable without erroring in php?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a list of php files that I am working on and in one php file I am able to get this function to work but only when it is set up in this manner.

```
<script>
    function addingredient() {
    var table = document.getElementById("ingredients_table");
    var row = table.insertRow(y);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = ' <select name="ingredients[]"  style="width: 200px"> <option value="option">option</option></select> ';
    cell2.innerHTML = ' <select name="measurements[]"  style="width: 200px"> <option value="option">option</option></select> ';
    cell3.innerHTML = ' <textarea style="width: 100px" class="form-control" name="amount[]" rows="1"> ';
    y++;
    changecontent();
}
function changecontent() {
<?php  ?>
}
</script>
```

Here is where my problem arises. I am not sure if I could use a .js file but I wrote everything I have done in .php for this project and so far I have my page displaying variables in a drop down box depending on what is on my server making it data driven. I have my java-script working where it inserts but I want to change the id and contents to my predefined variables like id = 1 and the cell would say tbs, id = 2 and cell says teaspn, and so on and so forth.

My issue arises when I try to access the variables that have these assignments. For some reason, when I keep this as is or remove the  it works but if I try to do anything with the php, it tells me that addingredient is not defined.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

One example that I know works is say I do

```
function changecontent() {
var temp = '<? ingredientslist ?>';
}
```

This will show temp as what is in the quotes when it's the values I assigned to make my drop down work.
If I do it again without the quotes, it simply says addingredient is undefined.

Comment: Please show what you are trying to do with PHP.

Comment: I hope you're not trying to make PHP code run inside your JavaScript, because that's impossible unless you use some form of AJAX.

Comment: create a .php page on that page inside script tag write this method then you can access php variable using var temp = <? $ingredientslist ?>; if $ingredientslist has some value i.e. if it is already set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** You can't directly pass the PHP variables into Javascript directly because they both are compiled at different time, PHP is compiled/interpreted at compile time and javascript is compiled at run time.

For your problem, I would suggest to use javascript to fetch the value from the drop down and AJAX to load the content dynamically

```
<script>
function addingredient() {
    //initialize your form elements
    var table = document.getElementById("ingredients_table");
    var row = table.insertRow(y);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = ' <select name="ingredients[]"  style="width: 200px" onchange="changeContent(this)"> <option value="option">option</option></select> ';
    cell2.innerHTML = ' <select name="measurements[]"  style="width: 200px" onchange="changeContent(this)"> <option value="option">option</option></select> ';
    cell3.innerHTML = ' <textarea style="width: 100px" class="form-control" name="amount[]" rows="1"> ';
}

function changeContent(element) {
    var selectedOption = element.selected.val();

    //Do a AJAX call to call your PHP script

    //And change the content in the container element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As much as I can notice, you're trying to use some functions from javascript in your php scripts, and that's impossible (php and javascript are different languages, they won't share functions), what you can do is passing some variables from one to other (I mean by using AJAX).

I would really like to help you more but I just don't understand.

In addition, all I can do for now:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$html = "<select name='ingredients[]'  style='width: 200px'>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $html .= "<option value='option'>$row['column']</option>";
}

$html .= "</select>";

echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: I would show you the file but it would be too long to understand but the point of it is that I have the files written in php. It's js for the most part and at times it includes php for accessing my database and such but I have this script written to add more elements to my page since I can't figure out how to do it in php or if it is even possible. I have it adding the extra elements but I don't know how to populate the dropdown box with elements from my server. It doesn't matter to me how I do it as long as it gets done.

Comment: @MarlinHankin the PHP code and the JavaScript code run on different computers.